# How to solve problem using gcc -pg on alpine?

Tags: c, gcc, dockerfile, alpine-linux, gprof

I have dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.18.2
WORKDIR /app
RUN apk add gdb gcc musl-dev make binutils
COPY ./src /app
RUN gcc main.c -pg -o app
```

But compilation fails with an error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/12.2.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find gcrt1.o: No such file or directory
```

Tried `find / -name gcrt1.o` but didn't find anything

Which package should be installed for gcrt1.o?

Comment: I found that the required file is in the [pcc-libs-dev](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86/pcc-libs-dev) package, but after installing it, the problem remains

Comment: You should add that information to the question, rather than in a comment. You can [edit] your question at any time, for any reason.